# Without page reloading conditional rendering does not work when session storage changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

window.sessionStorage.setItem('doesitwork', '1')


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
const sessionStorage = Boolean(window.sessionStorage.getItem("doesitwork"));

const App = () => <div>{sessionStorage && <h1>hello world!</h1>}</div>;

export default App;
```

I expect 'hello world' to appear when I start this application, but nothing happens until I reload the page.

The app is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-snowflake-tyijo?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is currently depending on the order in which the modules load, which leads to fragile code and can make reasoning about the code harder. Retrieve the `sessionStorage` value not at the top level of the module, but only when App is called:

```
const App = () => {
  const sessionStorage = Boolean(window.sessionStorage.getItem("doesitwork"));
  return <div>{sessionStorage && <h1>hello world!</h1>}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

With your current code, depending on module load order, the `App` module may run before the other module, resulting in the `sessionStorage =` line running before the `sessionStorage.setItem` line running.